# saving jQuery tag-it input as php array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, tag-it

I am using jQuery Tag-it! to create a "Skills" input form for my users. I have the UI of tag-it working, but I cannot get the user input into a PHP array. I am trying to serialize this array and save it to a mysql database for displaying later, but I can't even get the data into an array.

Here is the javascript initializing tag-it:

```
$('#skills').tagit({     
    allowSpaces: true,
    placeholderText: "Separate skills with a comma please",
    autocomplete: true
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <label class="add_label">Skills: </label>
    <ul id="skills" style="width: 275px; margin-bottom: 8px;"></ul>
</div>
```

This is the javascript that creates the input field where the user input is supposed to be stored:

```
if (!this.options.singleField) {
       var escapedValue = label.html();
       tag.append('<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="' + escapedValue + '" name="' + this.options.fieldName + '" />');
}
```

And this is the PHP which gets the user input -- this is the part that is not working. I cannot retrieve ANY data from the form:

```
$skillsArr = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['skills']);
```

When I do submit the form, the mysqli query executes and in the database I see "N;" where the serialized array should be.

How can I get the jQuery Tag-it values into a PHP array that I can serialize and save to a mysql database?

Comment: echo the mysql query somewhere, or have it go to error_log() so you can see what query is actually being run.

Comment: Try a `var_dump( $_REQUEST );` in your php handler file to see what data you're submitting and handle it accordingly.

Comment: or look at the post sent with the ajax request in your console log

Comment: Can you please explain to us your solution to this issue @TyBailey

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that tag-it will by default send the post request with data like this:

```
tags=foo&tags=bar&tags=blah
```

PHP will interpret that by making $_POST['tag'] ='blah'.  For PHP to handle it like an array the post data needs to look like:

```
tags[]=foo&tags[]=bar&tags[]=blah
```

The easiest way to solve this is just by changing the fieldName parameter when you setup tag-it, such as:

```
$('.taglist').tagit({
    allowSpaces: true,
    placeholderText: 'add new tag here...',
    fieldName: 'tags[]'
});
```

By simply changing the name to include the [] then it'll be interprested as you want by PHP and be an array.

Alternatively, if you're not able to adjust that you could always process the raw PHP data to get the tags as an array, like:

```
$query = array();
foreach (explode('&', file_get_contents('php://input')) as $kv) {
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $kv);
    $k = urldecode($k);
    $v = urldecode($v);
    if (!isset($query[$k])) {
        $query[$k] = $v;
    } else {
        if (is_array($query[$k])) {
            $query[$k][] = $v;
        } else {
            $query[$k] = array($query[$k], $v);
        }
    }
}
```

Now $query['tags'] will be an array as expected.

NB: If only one tag is sent then it'll end up being a string with the above code, so just make sure you cast it as an array if the result is going in a loop or something:

```
foreach((array)$query['tags'] as $tag) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to just do all the queries on the backend (php/mysqli).

That way the only thing I needed in my jQuery autocomplete was:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tagit").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
   source: "ajax-search.php",
}
  });
});
</script>
```

I just defined the source of the file. You can add the delimiter, etc to this as you want (I just modded the source instead).

But the primary function is from the php file, which returns a JSON encoded result.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php"); //Including our DB Connection file

    if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term'])) //if there's no search, exit
  exit;

    $keyword = trim($_REQUEST['term']);
    $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $keyword);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM animals WHERE english LIKE '%$keyword%' LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); //Run the Query

    $data = array(); //initialize array

    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row['row_id'],
    'label' => $row['english'], //This is the 'live return of the search
    'value' => $row['eng_dir'], //The value returned. Not needed if you're returning the label
    'latin' => $row['latin'] //Another result (you can add more)
       );
    }
     }
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();
  ?>
```

Then inside the tag-it.js file you can select what you want to push as a tag:

```
if (this.options.availableTags || this.options.tagSource || this.options.autocomplete.source) {
   var autocompleteOptions = {
   select: function(event, ui) {
     that.createTag(ui.item.id); //pushes the ID
 that.createTag(ui.item.value); //pushes the value
     that.createTag(ui.item.label); //pushes the label
     that.createTag(ui.item.latin); //pushes the extra variable
 // Preventing the tag input to be updated with the chosen value.
 return false;
    }
   };
  $.extend(autocompleteOptions, this.options.autocomplete);
```

The code above will return 4 instances of the same tag depending on your result.